Reporting the bad faith of coworkers to HR
Follow-up on Questions #1 and #2
Please read this carefully, I am surprized by some of your answers. The 3 way meeting that I requested was cancelled by the same colleague multiple times and it never happened.
I had asked HR to resend my job application to my manager, which they did. However, my manager canceled the three-way meeting he had promised and then went on an unknown leave from the company(we do not know when he will  be back).
As a result, I was left without an answer regarding my application. Subsequently, an employee (Employee Z) was promoted to handle my manager's responsibilities during his leave. Employee Z came to me and informed me that the company had decided to end my contract earlier than expected (giving two weeks notice). When I questioned this, mentioning that I still had two months remaining on my contract, he told me that this was the message he was instructed to deliver. He said that Ms. XYZ had asked him to inform me.
I then sent a message to Ms. XYZ requesting a meeting, but she did not respond. I approached her in person, and she said she was busy and could not meet with me. I explained that it was urgent and that I could not wait until next week, but she insisted that she had no time to meet and she can only let me speak for 5 minutes. She then stated that the company had decided to let me go due to budget constraints. She told me that she could not listen to further concerns and that I should put everything in writing and send it to her.
I complied by putting all my documents into an email and sending it to her, while also cc'ing several individuals in upper management. The following day, Ms. XYZ (company wide)announced that she would be completely stepping away from our project and that Mr. BYZ would now handle all HR-related issues. Since Mr. BYZ was cc'd in my email, he replied, advising me to report the issue to the HR Integrity Group within the company.(manager advised me to report the incidence to HR)
As of now, I am without a job due to the actions of three individuals within the company. If I report this incident to HR, I am concerned that they may blacklist my future job applications. The company is large, and I have been applying to other departments within it. What should I do now?
I would really like to provide my evidence and show their unfaithful decision and their abusive behavior over the past 1.5 year. What do I do in this situation?
I know I am not working with these people, but I am also very disturbed by them and mistreated for 1.5 year. I would like to report them before my leave.

It doesn’t appear you took any of the feedback or any advice you received from this community to heart. Your contract was not renewed and there is nothing you can do about that. Your previous questions didn’t mention any abusive behavior. You probably don’t have to worry about being black listed due to behavior you haven’t yet done. It’s clear based on the description you provided they were unhappy with your work. You seem upset others were promoted and most definitely bitter about not the job you applied to, it’s good your passionate about the job, but you must not display so much emotion.

@Donald, Last year, they renewed my contract. Why are they only now unhappy with my work? Why have they always provided positive feedback and never raised any issues about my performance? even now they did not argue about my performance even I asked them to come and have meeting with me they just cancelled the performance meeting

There are many reasons the company do not want to renew your contract, which may have nothing to do with your job performance, skills, or work ethics. For example, they could find someone else who can work for less money, or the company decide to cut cost because they lose profit or want to invest more money on other more profitable products, etc...

they advertised my role, and they are in the process of hiring someone, they just delaying the hiring process to make me leave first

I voted to close. The question boils down to "I dont have a job and i think i would have had a right to a specific job". The first one can be adressed by applying to other jobs the second one by "contact a lawyer".

@nikki - I would ask them. They don’t have to hire you. You are a contractor. They don’t have to get rid of you before they hire someone else, in fact they could keep you on for another 2 months, and ask you to train the permanent employee if they wanted. Last year doesn’t matter this year they didn’t renew. Your last question suggested they wanted a new performance review. So did that review happen, your last question, hinted you didn’t even want to hold it.

I requested performance review, and NO It did not happen, they cancelled IT. For god seek please read the question

Please stop beating a dead horse. This company isn't your future. Don't waste your time and efforts on them. Move on. There are plenty of other companies out there.

there is some shuffling happening in the company. Those individuals have hopes to become a manager, I can report them to HR so HR can review their work ethic and performance. They will lose their chance of getting higher positions.


What should I do now?

Let it go: they don't want you, so you need to look forward and focus on your next adventure.

If I report this incident to HR, I am concerned that they may blacklist my future job applications.

They already may have. You made quite the spectacle out of this and no one wants drama. What makes you think HR doesn't already now about it? HR typically handles contracts and terminations.

I would like to report them before my leave?

What for? What do you expect would happen? Chances are the powers at be are well aware of how this went down and are ok with it. It sounds a bit like there is major reshuffling happening anyway, so your story is unlikely to make any difference.

As a contractor we are not in contact with HR, I am hired by a third party company to work for this company. We do not have acess to the internal HR,  Internal HR is for their employees.

@programmer_smart - As a contractor you essentially demanded a meeting with your boss or their boss or even someone with the authority to cancel your contract. As long as the individuals you alienate are around I wouldn’t count on coming back.

@Donald, what do you mean? could you please read the story properly? you are not clear

@nikki - I actually did read the story properly.

Complaining won't solve your problem.
You better spend that time to look another opportunity rather than complaining.

It will not solve my problem, but I can let the others know their intention, and I am pretty sure they can be fired in the future.

@nikki "I am concerned that they may blacklist my future job applications." It is your loss in either situation.

They already terminated my contract for no reason. What else will they do?

@procrastinator1771, could you please let others with relative experience answer the question?

@nikki - A company doesn’t need a reason to terminate or not renew a contract with a contractor. They clearly were unhappy. You don’t terminate a contract with a contractor you been working with for over a year immediately if your happy. Lack of funding only explains part of your situation.

They gave me 15 days notice, it is not immediate, my contract was renewed last year, I am working for them for 2 years, please do not reply if you do not know the answer.

@Nikki Not liking the answer doesn't mean it isn't good advice. Devote your energy to improving your future, rather than obsessing over your past.

The amount of energy and time I spend at my work here was also part of my future, I can not allow people gossip behind me

@nikki - They might or they might not and unfortunately there is absolutely nothing you can do about that.

@nikki A very important life lesson to learn is that you cannot control other people.

but I can report them, why do you think reporting is not good? for me it is a matter of sending an email. I already documented the incidence.

@nikki, because you, as a "terminated" person, have zero credibility to the employer. Reporting them only makes you look worse for any future work at any company that they go to. People remember that you caused drama, not how good you worked.

what about writing an email to the 3rd party company that they hired me to work for that company? can I ask them to find me a job instead of ghosting me?

@DavidR, could you clarify why this will affect me with my future job applications to other companies? these people were abusing me and I am not going to ask them to write me any reference. My manager is insecure, and swings his words.

@nikki Coworkers do go to other companies. My experience is that they remembered what I was like, and they didn't want me at the new company. It has cost me opportunities.

tables also turns
